# Всплывающий div при наведении на div в ie8

Tags: javascript, css

Приветствую всех вошедших.

Есть конструкция взятая с хэшкода. Позволяет при наведении на div, показать другой div. Просто, и быстро работает, можно применить несколько раз на одной странице. К сожалению это добро не работает на IE8. Может ли кто подсказать, как написать свойства css (или css не поможет, и потребуется что либо на JS ?), что бы в IE8 работало так же как и в нормальных браузерах?

```
//css
.vicvet { position:relative; text-align:justify;  }
.vicvet .vis { display:none; position:absolute; top:-04px; left:-04px; z-index:5; }
.vicvet:hover .vis { display:block }

//html
<div class="vicvet">
что либо, на что наводим
 <div class="vis">
 при наведении, всплывает div
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если так попробовать?? http://jsfiddle.net/37rbb/

Comment: Спасибо, шикарный вариант решения моего вопроса!

Comment: Реально помогло или это просто стёб??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите в начале html-файла

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Или какой-нибудь другой доктайп. Без доктайпа IE8 переходит в quirks mode, где hover работает только с элементом

```
  <a>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Незнал. К сожалению тепеь у меня не работает кое какое решение на JS, но это уже другой вопрос. :hover начал работать

Answer (score 1):

В IE N версий псевдокласс :hover работает только для ссылок, по этому либо прикручивать [csshover.htc](http://4dle.ru/webmaster/css/1147155375-csshover-dlja-ljubogo-jelementa-v-ie.html) или юзать javascript [hover() jquery](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=mouse+over+out&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&tok=Seq6wIY4khWSuYcX8wd0yA&pq=mouse%20over%20out&cp=6&gs_id=s&xhr=t&q=hover()+jquery&pf=p&client=opera&hs=56w&channel=suggest&sclient=psy-ab&oq=hover(&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.Yms&fp=a3faa99598a56e0a&biw=1366&bih=684)