# Отображение div при наведении на изображение

Tags: php, javascript, css

предположим есть несколько картинок. при наведении на одну из них хочется отображать всплывающий div с некоторой информацией из базы

думаю даже стоит подгружать при наведении, т.е. предположим не тянуть 150 объектов с описанием, а при наведении динамически подгружать.

хотя 150 объектов можно и одним запросом вытянуть.

но тогда где хранить эти дивы? скрывать до наведения? как это правильно реализуется?

Comment: зачем скрывать? их можно добавлять в DOM в момент наведения и делать запрос к базе за контентом, затем просто удалить из DOM

Comment: пока смотрю на вариант http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/182326/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-div-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-div-%D0%B2-ie8

Comment: можете конечно и так сделать, просто добавлять руками 150 дивов на страницу очень утомительное занятие, если конечно это все динамически в цикле не выводится

Comment: ну в принципе и картинки же руками не добавляются. так что просто дергать не только путь до картинки но и описание

Comment: я ж не знаю что у вас и как)) Ситуации разные бывают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выводите картинку вместе с описанием в каком-нибудь отдельном блоке.

Например, https://jsfiddle.net/qLmLtcsr/

html:

```
<div class="frame">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="image">
  <div class="image-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed augue ligula. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam placerat erat vel odio aliquam, nec elementum arcu pellentesque. Donec eu enim eget purus venenatis molestie. Duis semper neque eget molestie vehicula. Vivamus volutpat congue vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam quam felis, ultrices id fringilla in, lacinia blandit neque. Maecenas leo felis, placerat sit amet dui sit amet, faucibus luctus lacus. Donec tempor accumsan nisl quis ultrices</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.image {
  display: block;
}
.image-desc {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 205px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}
.frame:hover .image-desc {
  display: block;
}
```

У динамической подгрузки описания есть один существенный минус: если в описании содержится важная для поисковых машин информация, они её не получат

Comment: а чем это лучще\хуже http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/182326/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-div-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-div-%D0%B2-ie8

Comment: Ничем. По сути это аналог

Comment: ваш вариант позволяет навесить ondblclick